# Entity Framework Contains/In Clause with SQLCE

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am trying to select items from an SQLCE table, where a field exists in a string array.  This is easy in SQL with:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableX
WHERE SomeField In
([comma delimited array values]);
```

I am having a difficult time transposing this to LINQ.  The following would logically work, but it is receiving this error:  *LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String], System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.*

```
var result = from c in DB.TableX
             where someStringArray.Contains(c.SomeField)
             select c;
```

Please let me know if anyone has any ideas or advice.

Thanks!

**Update:**

The following, reccomended below, throws a NotSupportedException, with error message, where class X is the class calling the enumeration: *Unable to create a constant value of type 'NamespaceX.ClassX'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context*.

```
var result = from c in DB.TableX
             where someStringArray.Any(s => s == c.SomeField)
             select c;
```

Comment: The answer below didn't work? It did for me.

Comment: Check this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/03/26/tip-8-writing-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities.aspx

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var result = from c in DB.TableX
             where someStringArray.Any(s => s == c.SomeField)
             select c;
```

Please mark as answer if this solves your problem.

Comment: Use .Contains() instead of .Any()